# Detach footer from the main container

Tags: html, css

The web page layout of my website look something as follows:

The web page layout of my website look something as follows:

```
<body>
<div class="container">
   <div class="sidebar">
   </div>
   <div class="content">
   </div>
</div>

<div class="pre-footer">
</div>
<div class="footer">
</div>
</body>
```

Css:

```
body  {background:#eaeaea url('../images/bg/sfere.jpg') no-repeat top center fixed;}
.footer {float:left;width:100%;height:67px;background:url('../images/bottom.png') bottom center;bottom:0px;left:0px;}
.container{padding-top:5px;margin-left:100px;margin-right:auto;}
.sidebar {float:left;width:220px;min-height:610px;text-align:center;}
.home {margin:178px 0 0 100px;padding:0 10px 0px 10px;width:800px;float:left;}
.pre-footer {float:left;width:98%;height:100px;position:relative;background:url('../images/pre-footer.png') bottom center;left:15px;bottom:-32px;}
```

All the elements are appearing fine in layout. However, the problem is when the height of the container is less, the footer elements stick below the container and don't stay in the footer position. Similarly, if I manually fix the height as 600px to make it look like a footer, on browser resize, the footer still stick below the container and doesn't look like a footer.

How do I rectify this problem?

Comment: What are you getting at?  Are you wanting the footer to be fixed to the bottom of the viewport?

Comment: Use min-height for `.container` class and set it to something like `400px`

Comment: @simnom: Yes! But not like a sticky footer. It should be at the bottom always

Comment: @asprin: That does the task for and footer stays at the bottom. But the footer then doesn't get to the bottom when the browser is resized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use fixed position for your footer.

```
div.footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 50px; /* change this as needed */
}
```

and specify a bottom padding to your body to ensure all content is visible when scrolled.

```
body {
    padding-bottom: 50px; /* change this to the max-height given for your footer */
}
```

Comment: I think you mistook it to be a sticky footer. What I am looking for is how to place the footer always at the bottom, even if it might not be visible in the viewport

Comment: Ahh, ok. I thought you were looking to implement a sticky footer.

Comment: Looks like it's only an issue with firefox. When I do full screen the footer also moves up. Rest of the browsers are showing the footer fine. Thanks for the help though : )